# How to pass array of objects to material vue autocomplete

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-material

**Background**

I am passing an array of objects to a material autocomplete which can be found [here](https://vuematerial.io/components/autocomplete).

When I select a item in the list the first time it throws an error and then if I click the item again it selects it as expected. This same process repeats each time I click the items in the autocomplete.

**Example Error**

> [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "input": "TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'constructor' of undefined"

**Example Code**

```
<template>
<md-autocomplete 
  v-model="customer"
  :md-options="customers" 
  @md-changed="getCustomers" 
  @md-opened="getCustomers"
  @md-selected="getSelected" 
>
</md-autocomplete>
</template>

<script>
data: () => ({
    customers: [],
    customer: "", // I also tried making this a {}
 }),
methods: {
getCustomers(searchTerm) {
  this.customers = new Promise(resolve => {
    if (!searchTerm) {
      resolve(this.GET_CUSTOMERS);
    } else {
      const term = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
      this.customers = this.GET_CUSTOMERS.filter(({ email }) => {
      email.toLowerCase().includes(term);
  });
    resolve(this.customers);
  }
  });
},


getSelected() {
     console.log(this.customer);
   },
}
</script>
```

**Data Example**

```
GET_CUSOTMERS: [
  { client_id: 1, email: "example@example.com" },
  { client_id: 2, email: "example@example.com" }
];
```

**Question**

What does this error mean and how do I fix it? I have read that there was a bug in an angular using autocomplete from material that through this error a few years back but I am optimistic that this is currently fixable and not a bug for material vue.

Comment: did you try to fill customers array in the mounted hook?

Comment: I did not, I will give that a try.

Comment: I tried that and it still gives me the same exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Troubleshooting the error

Based on the `MdAutocomplete`'s [`input`-handler](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/blob/24e63ba/src/components/MdAutocomplete/MdAutocomplete.vue#L195) source code, `searchTerm` is `undefined` in your case (hence the error about accessing `constructor` of `undefined`):

```
// MdAutocomplete.vue: onInput()
if (this.searchTerm.constructor.toString().match(/function (\w*)/)[1].toLowerCase() !== 'inputevent') {
         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

And `searchTerm` is normally [equal to its `value` prop](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/blob/24e63ba/src/components/MdAutocomplete/MdAutocomplete.vue#L80):

```
data () {
  return {
    searchTerm: this.value,
    //...
  }
},
watch: {
  value (val) {
    this.searchTerm = val
  },
  //...
},
```

...unless an item is [selected](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/blob/24e63ba/src/components/MdAutocomplete/MdAutocomplete.vue#L219):

```
selectItem (item, $event) {
  const content = $event.target.textContent.trim()
  this.searchTerm = content
  //...
}
```

So when the error occurs, it's likely that the `value` of `MdAutocomplete` is somehow `undefined` (from your `v-model`), causing `searchTerm` to also be `undefined`. When you select an item, the `searchTerm` is reset to the text content of the selection, and no error occurs.

I'm not able to reproduce those exact symptoms with the code snippet in the OP, but seemingly unrelated errors occur: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ppl9699x0). Perhaps the question is missing salient details to reproduce the problem.

#### Using an object array for md-autocomplete options

- The `md-options` (i.e., `this.customers` here) promise must return an array of strings, so you'd have to convert your object array into the expected format (using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)):

  ```
  this.customers = new Promise(resolve => {
    if (!searchTerm) {
      resolve(GET_CUSTOMERS.map(x => x.email));   // <-- map to `email` property
    } else {
      const term = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
      this.customers = GET_CUSTOMERS.filter(/*...*/).map(x => x.email);   // <-- map to `email` property
      resolve(this.customers);
    }
  }
  ```
- The `Array.prototype.filter` callback must return a Boolean for any filtering to occur. The following [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax), used as the callback, returns nothing:

  ```
  GET_CUSTOMERS.filter(({ email }) => {
    email.toLowerCase().includes(term);
  });
  ```

  You could either remove the brackets of the arrow function:

  ```
  GET_CUSTOMERS.filter(({ email }) => email.toLowerCase().includes(term));
  ```

  or use a `return` statement:

  ```
  GET_CUSTOMERS.filter(({ email }) => {
    return email.toLowerCase().includes(term);
  });
  ```

[demo (fixed)](https://codesandbox.io/s/n0n9lwj5xl)